# How to change Default port no when Gitlab installed on local system with domain name

Tags: gitlab

I tried to change configuration in /var/opt/gitlab/nginx/conf/gitlab-http.conf

/etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb this two paths.

But am using a domain name so i have to add port no at the end of domain name. I wanted to use only domain name to logon to my gitlab account